# SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import. ╷ 4 │ @import './bootstrap-dark.scss';

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I just installed Boostrap dark theme from:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-dark-5

And I am trying to import it in a theme.scss file inside of src/assets/theme.scss:

```
// Dark Theme
@import './bootstrap-dark.scss';
```

This is inside of React 16.13.1

but it cannot find the stylesheet.

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "my_app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "bootstrap-dark-5": "^1.1.3",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-codemirror2": "^7.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "react-split": "^2.0.14",
    "reactstrap": "^9.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.66.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

I installed sass, is my path wrong? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `creat-react-app`, you can follow the official guide to import the Bootstrap to the app, but instead of Bootstrap, do it for the `bootstrap-dark-5`.

However, there is a couple issues regarding to this bootstrap-dark-5 module:

1. The SCSS import is broken. You can import the `bootstarp-dark.scss` file from its module, but it's missing some files in its module.
2. The only way to import the `bootstrap-dark.scss` file is to download each of the scss files locally, manually fix the import path, or patch the import path.

Therefore, the easiest way to get you kick start the Bootstrap theme would be do that the official Create-react-app way --

Either add the following to the `index.tsx/jsx` file (or the most parent file)

```
import 'bootstrap-dark-5/dist/css/bootstrap-dark.css';
```

Or, add those into the main scss file

```scss
@import 'bootstrap-dark-5/dist/css/bootstrap-dark.css';
```

And you will have your Bootstrap Dark Theme.

Doc to official Create React App for adding Bootstrap: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-bootstrap/